# How to include an external JavaScript file in Haml

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby, sinatra, haml

I want to add styles and functions dynamically using an external JavaScript and jQuery file, but it is constantly throwing an error.

The Ruby code is:

```
# myapp.rb
require 'sinatra'
require 'sinatra/reloader'
require 'haml'

get '/' do
    @contacts = [
        {
            name: "Petit",
            class: "K1"
        }
    ]

    haml :index
end

get '/about-us' do
    haml :about
end
```

The Haml code is:

```
!!!
%html
    %head
        = javascript_include_tag "actions"

    %body
        %h1#title.titles
            This is a page title

        %ul
            - @contacts.each do |contact|
                %li
                    = "#{contact[:name]}'s class is #{contact[:class]}"

        %a{ href: "/about-us"}
            About
```

This line seems to be the problem:

```
= javascript_include_tag "actions"
```

The error is when I run the application in the browser:

```
NoMethodError at /
undefined method `javascript_include_tag' for #<Sinatra::Application:"some hex address here">
```

Without that line of code it runs fine, and the embedded JavaScript works too. I haven't been able to link an external JavaScript file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your directory looks like this:

```
ruby-web/
| public/
|-| css/
|-|-| styles.css
|
|-| javascript/
|-|-| jquery-3.5.1.min.js
|-|-| actions.js
|
| views/
|-| index.haml
|-| about.haml
| my-app.rb
```

and your Ruby code looks like this:

```
# myapp.rb
require 'sinatra'
require 'sinatra/reloader'
require 'haml'

get '/' do
    haml :index
end

get '/about-us' do
    haml :about
end
```

Your `index.haml` is going to be the root page which is going to be displayed when you connect to the server, so your `index.haml` code should look like this:

```
!!!
%html
    %head
        /Styles :
        %link{:href => "css/styles.css", :type => "text/css"}
        /Scripts :
        %script{:src => "javascript/jquery-3.5.1.min.js", :type => "text/javascript"}
        %script{:src => "javascript/actions.js", :type => "text/javascript"}

    %body
        %h1#title
            Equations

        %div#about
            %footer#footer
                %a{ href: "/about-us"}
                    About
```

Notice the `%link` and `%script` tags in the Haml code, and look at the paths given in `:src` and `:href`.

It is:

```
:src => "javascript/actions.js"
```

and

```
:href => "css/styles.css"
```

Not:

```
:src => "public/javascript/actions.js"
```

and

```
:href => "public/css/styles.css"
```

even though the script and styles are in the `public` folder.

Nor:

```
:src => "../public/javascript/actions.js"
```

and

```
:href => "../public/css/styles.css"
```

even though the script and styles are in `../public/javascript/` or `../public/css/` relative to `index.haml.`

Now that you have a public folder containing the script and styles, you can link to them with the method mentioned above.

Comment: Congratulations on your first answer. Please read "[answer]" and its linked pages. Grammar, including spelling and punctuation, are important on SO. Stack Overflow isn't a forum or message board, it's like an online reference book. This applies to questions too and is mentioned in "[ask]" and its linked pages.